# PHP fails on JSON encoding data from Aurora MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, elasticsearch, amazon-aurora

I've recently migrated an application from MySQL to Amazon Aurora MySQL service. My application fetches data from this database and use it to search one of the Elasticsearch index.

The underlying HTTP client of PHP Elasticsearch library encodes the query data to JSON before sending to Elasticsearch server. I found that sometimes the `json_encode` call fails and returns false when passing the data retrieved from database. This occurs at random intervals so I couldn't locate the exact reason.

My findings are given below:

1. The data retrieved from the database sometimes contains binary strings and `json_encode` fails when this data is passed to it.
2. We use UTF8 encoding at the database level so this couldn't be an issue.

[Screenshot of database response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmNrS.png)

Anybody here faced similar issue with Aurora or MySQL database, or is it just an issue from PHP itself?

Comment: So you are saying that the database column that should contain a JSON String sometimes contains binary data, right?

Comment: I would start by checking the database. Did this binary data appear when you migrated the database or is there some of your code that has a Opps in it that is storing binary data

Comment: You cannot lay the blame on PHP's `json_encode()` for failing to convert data it was never designed to convert

Comment: No, the database column only contains a search text. We then build an Elasticsearch query as an array and then pass it to the PHP Elasticsearch client library. The underlying implementation of this library use `json_encode` to encode it before sending to the Elasticsearch server.

Comment: Also, yes these issues came up after the application was moved to Aurora MySQL.

Comment: Have you actually CHECHED the database?

Comment: Yes. I have checked the database. The data successfully gets encoded sometimes. This only happens at random intervals. Thats the reason I doubted if it is related to Aurora or PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue from AWS Aurora itself. Similar issue was faced by another person and the AWS support team informed him thats its now fixed globally.

[Link to reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/abvi0x/my_visual_notes_on_amazon_aurora_serverless/ed5awri).

Answer (score 0):

Never assume anything when comes to use php and mysql... 8/10 what you are thinking is not the problem...is the problem...

so, try this:

## Force an encoding

```
function array_utf8_encode($dat){
        if (is_string($dat))
            return utf8_encode($dat);
        if (!is_array($dat))
            return $dat;
        $ret = array();
        foreach ($dat as $i => $d)
            $ret[$i] = self::array_utf8_encode($d);
        return $ret;
 }

$my_db_arr = array_utf8_encode($my_db_arr);

// Now let's encode
$json = json_encode($my_db_arr);
```

**NOTE** the function array_utf8_encode is not mine... but i honestly don't rememeber where i found it here on stackOverflow...otherwise i would put the link and relative credits...

## Are there some errors ?

```
var_dump(json_last_error_msg());
```

[json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Have a good day,

Antonio

Comment: The problem is its not always failing to encode the data. Most of the times it successfully encodes to JSON. This occurs only at random intervals.

Comment: then try to leave json_last_error_msg, in this way you can know why is failing